# Why do I get "Unknown action The action 'show' could not be found"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, static, controller, routes

I am trying to create a series of static pages for a Rails app.  The "about" page works fine but when I try using the same method for the "terms" page I get an unknown action.  I am assuming this is with my controller.

This is my routes.rb file:

```
resources :pages
get "pages/index"

match '/about' => 'pages#about'
match ':permalink', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'show', :as => 'about'

match '/terms' => 'pages#terms'
match ':permalink', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'show', :as => 'terms'


root :to => 'pages#index'
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :search_performed?
  def index
    @search = Farm.search(params[:q])
    @json = @search.result.to_gmaps4rails 
  end

  protected
  def search_performed?
    params[:q].present?
  end

  def about
  end

  def feedback
  end

  def terms
  end

end
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what the parameter as is for, its intended to customize named routes. 
via the doc
[ActionDispatch::Routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html)
Rails matches routes in order from top to bottom, so this is the behavior you are seeing.

Extract the common logic between terms and about and have about and terms point to their own controller actions.

Answer (score 8):

My case was different from above cases , so i'm writing for the sake of help .
I viewed the same error and i understand that error was due to some routing problems , while here was my route

```
resources 'customers'
  get "/customers/dashboard" => "customers#dashboard"
```

Then i changed the arrangement

```
  get "/customers/dashboard" => "customers#dashboard"
resources 'customers'
```

My routes worked - Happy coding :)

Answer (score -1):

Because you did not create action `show` in your `PagesController`

```
def show
end
```

`:as => 'about'` in your routes means that you can call this helper from code like `about_path` or `about_url`, but it still need `:action => 'show'`

Comment: If I have only the routes: `match '/about' => 'pages#about'`, and   `match '/show' => 'pages#show'`
then  `localhost:3000/about` displays the about view, and `localhost:3000/show` displays the show view.  But if I add the route: `match ':permalink', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'show', :as => 'about'` after the first two routes, then `localhost:3000/show` produces a Routing Error: `No route matches {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"show"}`  Why is that? rake routes:
about  /about(.:format)      pages#about
 show  /show(.:format)       pages#show
about  /:permalink(.:format) pages#show

Comment: You have two routes for the same action: `match '/show' => 'pages#show'` and `match ':permalink', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'show'`